# C# - Bank check (Balance, transactions)

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, banking

I just started on a personal project for scouting-groups, it is a webapp which will be build on the frontend in Angular2 and the backend will be a restfull server(asp.net/C#).

a part of my project will need to read or contact diffrent bankaccounts and check if the contribution of a certain month is paid.

the question is: Where to start?

Comment: Some tutorials on ASP.NET, C#, Angular2, and other related technologies would be where to start I guess.  Also of use would be any API documentation for the external services you wish to use (banks?).

Comment: thx but the problem is that in the netherlands the banks dont offer any API. So any advice on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to import transaction files. A direct connection to banks are most of the time only for big companies and is a lot of work to implement (if they let you). Most banks have multiple file types to export transactions, choose the most common and implement this.

Comment: so i should couple a scoutingclub account to a bank, and then import each day, week or month a transactionfile. Oke thank for the idea, i will investigate more about this subject.